# Can/should I depend on WebLogic's bundled modules

Tags: java, dependencies, weblogic

My target platform is a WebLogic 12c application server.

I have an ear-project, which on startup requires e.g. `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`.

I know that this class - an related classes - can be found in `<WL_HOME>/modules/com.bea.core.apache.commons.logging.api_1.1.1.jar`, but it is not by default available on the classspath.

In such cases - am I supposed to somehow make the jar file in `<WL_HOME>/modules`available on the classpath - or should I provide whatever jar file I find suitable - either bundled in the application, or placed in `<WL_HOME>/user_projects/domains/<mydomain>/lib`?

If I am to use the one in the `<WL_HOME>/modules` folder - how do I configure my domain to make it available?

To me it seems reasonable that the jar files in the modules folder should be considered *provided dependencies*, but so far I have been unable to find the right way to enable them as such - I have been browsing for an answer for hours:-)

UPDATE:
I know I can simply add them to the CLASSPATH variable in the server startup script - my question is more like - should I? Is there a better way - or should I completely forget about `<WL_HOME>/modules`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a short-sighted approach.

- you need to reboot the server to upgrade libraries
- *every* app on the server must be okay with those libraries in their claspath

Weblogic has the concept of [Shared JEE Libraries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/libraries.htm#WLPRG335) ([example](https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/weblogic_server_shared_librari_1)). In short, you add extra lines to MANIFEST.MF and configure the jar differently, then you can reference it in other apps using `weblogic-application.xml` or whatever.

The point is that you can upgrade the library without restarting the server (provided you gave it a version like `1.1` (there were bugs last time I named it `1.1.1` - it needed to be able to cast it to a floating-point number to seamlessly upgrade)).

If you just want to include some libraries but *not* share them outside the app, then just specify the correct `<prefer-application-packages>` or `< prefer-web-inf-classes>` element, depending on whether you have an EAR or a WAR.

Comment: So - you would prefer a self contained war or ear - except perhaps for dependencies that are required to be aligned across applications, or are tightly coupled to the servlet container?

Comment: That's correct. The only things you should install as libraries in Weblogic itself are server-related stuff, like FIPS encryption modules, AWS SQS drivers or whatever.

Stuff that is common to many apps but that would just be a pain to update 40 times (like joda-time, which you need to update the timezone database every time Fiji changes its mind on daylight savings time dates) should go in a shared library, just for ease of maintenance. Plus your in-house libraries of course.